# Index not being used on join

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have this query, but for some reason (As far as I can see), the index on `trackings.visitor_id` is not being used, resulting in a slow (50ms) nested loop. I am aware that `COUNT` performance is not the best, but it's still a relatively small dataset, so I'd think that 50ms is too much.

I am just starting out diagnosing query performance, so pardon my ignorance

```
SELECT v0."id"
    ,v0."app_id"
    ,v0."first_seen"
    ,v0."last_seen"
    ,v0."last_heard_from"
    ,v0."last_contacted"
    ,v0."last_page_viewed"
    ,v0."sessions"
    ,v0."seen_welcome_message"
    ,v0."email"
    ,v0."data"
    ,v0."name"
    ,v0."type"
    ,v0."avatar"
    ,c1."id"
    ,c1."last_message"
    ,c1."last_activity"
    ,c1."visitor_id"
    ,c1."app_id"
    ,c1."inserted_at"
    ,c1."updated_at"
    ,(
        SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(t))
        FROM trackings t
        WHERE t.visitor_id = v0."id"
        )
    ,count(v0."id") OVER ()
FROM "visitors" AS v0
INNER JOIN "conversations" AS c1 ON c1."visitor_id" = v0."id"
INNER JOIN "apps" AS a2 ON a2."id" = c1."app_id"
LEFT JOIN "trackings" AS t3 ON (t3."visitor_id" = v0."id")
    AND (t3."visitor_id" = v0."id")
INNER JOIN "accounts" AS a4 ON a4."id" = a2."account_id"
WHERE (a2."id" = $1)
    AND (
        (v0."name" ILIKE $2)
        OR (v0."email" ILIKE $3)
        )
    AND (first_seen <= NOW() - ($4 || ' days')::interval)
    AND (last_seen > NOW() - ($5 || ' days')::interval)
GROUP BY v0."id"
    ,c1."id"
ORDER BY v0."last_seen" DESC LIMIT $6
```

Result of EXPLAIN

```
Limit  (cost=10925.55..10925.62 rows=30 width=612) (actual time=94.938..94.946 rows=30 loops=1)
2     ->  Sort  (cost=10925.55..10926.85 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=94.936..94.939 rows=30 loops=1)
3           Sort Key: v0.last_seen
4           Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 50kB
5           ->  WindowAgg  (cost=4766.27..10910.16 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=72.447..94.439 rows=386 loops=1)
6                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4766.27..7837.56 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=71.757..71.986 rows=386 loops=1)
7                       Group Key: v0.id, c1.id
8                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1759.72..4763.66 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=21.209..71.118 rows=488 loops=1)
9                             Hash Cond: ((v0.id)::text = (t3.visitor_id)::text)
10                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1751.56..4752.22 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=21.075..70.715 rows=386 loops=1)
11                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..13.26 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.025..0.108 rows=1 loops=1)
12                                        Join Filter: ((a2.account_id)::text = (a4.id)::text)
13                                        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 134
14                                        ->  Seq Scan on apps a2  (cost=0.00..8.22 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.010..0.057 rows=1 loops=1)
15                                              Filter: ((id)::text = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'::text)
16                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 257
17                                        ->  Seq Scan on accounts a4  (cost=0.00..3.35 rows=135 width=24) (actual time=0.005..0.028 rows=135 loops=1)
18                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1751.56..4733.75 rows=521 width=612) (actual time=21.041..70.491 rows=386 loops=1)
19                                        Hash Cond: ((v0.id)::text = (c1.visitor_id)::text)
20                                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on visitors v0  (cost=365.51..3275.51 rows=17860 width=456) (actual time=8.500..52.584 rows=18693 loops=1)
21                                              Recheck Cond: (last_seen > (now() - ('14 days'::cstring)::interval))
22                                              Filter: ((((name)::text ~~* '%%'::text) OR ((email)::text ~~* '%%'::text)) AND (first_seen <= (now() - ('1 days'::cstring)::interval)))
23                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 304
24                                              Heap Blocks: exact=1285
25                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "visitors_last_seen_DESC_NULLS_LAST_index"  (cost=0.00..361.05 rows=19300 width=0) (actual time=8.257..8.257 rows=18997 loops=1)
26                                                    Index Cond: (last_seen > (now() - ('14 days'::cstring)::interval))
27                                        ->  Hash  (cost=1369.60..1369.60 rows=1316 width=156) (actual time=12.497..12.497 rows=1306 loops=1)
28                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 203kB
29                                              ->  Seq Scan on conversations c1  (cost=0.00..1369.60 rows=1316 width=156) (actual time=0.009..11.675 rows=1306 loops=1)
30                                                    Filter: ((app_id)::text = 'ASnYW1-RgCl0I'::text)
31                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 42822
32                            ->  Hash  (cost=5.29..5.29 rows=229 width=24) (actual time=0.123..0.123 rows=229 loops=1)
33                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 13kB
34                                  ->  Seq Scan on trackings t3  (cost=0.00..5.29 rows=229 width=24) (actual time=0.004..0.037 rows=229 loops=1)
35                SubPlan 1
36                  ->  Aggregate  (cost=5.87..5.89 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.055..0.056 rows=1 loops=386)
37                        ->  Seq Scan on trackings t  (cost=0.00..5.86 rows=3 width=76) (actual time=0.048..0.052 rows=0 loops=386)
38                              Filter: ((visitor_id)::text = (v0.id)::text)
39                              Rows Removed by Filter: 229
40  Planning time: 2.629 ms
41  Execution time: 95.170 ms
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The join between visitors and conversations is generating most of the cost in this query.

You're joining 18693 visitors with 1306 conversations. Postgres decided that instead of checking visitors.id index 1306 times it would be faster to just get all 18693 interesting rows from visitors and use hash join. It may be wrong about this.

You can tune [random_page_cost closer to seq_page_cost](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html), to push Postgres for more aggressive index usage.